# Textnode getting cropped when using html2Canvas to covert html to pdf

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I started using html2Canvas. I'm trying to convert the below donut chart into a pdf using html2canvas and jspdf.

[image]

The result is as follows:

[image]

We can make out that text gets cropped.

Then I tried to change the text next to donut chart to this :

[image]

The result is so peculiar:

[image]

Why do only specific text nodes getting converted by html2Canvas? Why is the rest of it cropped? What is the programmatic workaround. Any help would be appreciated.